# Regarding solutions of ordinary differential equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, fundamental-solution

Got into a problem with the solution of this one:

$$
x\cos\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)(x\text{d}x+y\text{d}y)=y\sin\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)(x\text{d}y-y\text{d}x)
$$

I can identify differentials of $xy$ and $\frac{x}{y}$ and also of $\cos$ and $\sin$ functions but how should I manipulate the equation into a solvable form?

Comment: write your equation in the form $$x\cos\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)(x+y\frac{dy}{dx})=y\sin(y/x)(x\frac{dy}{dx}-y)$$ and set $$\frac{y}{x}=u$$

Comment: Divide through by $x\ dx.$  Now you have a homogeneous diff eq (everything in terms of $\frac {y}{x}$).  Try $u = \frac yx\implies y = ux$

Comment: Oh. I missed this point totally. Thank you people.

Comment: @DougM, I too thought to use that substitution, can you see an error in my answer, as I can't reconcile the final integral

Comment: @leProfesseur have you typed the question correct?

Comment: @MyGlasses yes the question is typed correct, I rechecked it.

Answer (score 1):

We have:

$x \cos (\frac{y}{x})(x dx+ydy) = y \sin(\frac{y}{x})(xdy-ydx)$

$\Rightarrow x \cos (\frac{y}{x})(x + y\frac{dy}{dx}) = y \sin(\frac{y}{x})(x\frac{dy}{dx} - y)$

Let $u = \frac{y}{x}$

Then $\frac{du}{dx} = \frac{x\frac{dy}{dx} - y}{x^2} = \frac{\frac{dy}{dx} - u}{x}$

$\Rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx} = x\frac{du}{dx} + u$

Then we substitute this in:

$x\cos u [x+ux(x\frac{du}{dx} +u)] = ux\sin u(x^{2}\frac{du}{dx}+ux-ux)$

$\Rightarrow x^2\cos u [1+u(x\frac{du}{dx} +u)] = ux^3\sin u \frac{du}{dx}$

$\Rightarrow ux\sin u \frac{du}{dx} -\cos u - ux\cos u \frac{du}{dx}-u^2\cos u = 0$

$\Rightarrow ux(\sin u - \cos u)\frac{du}{dx}-(u^2+1)\cos u = 0$

$\Rightarrow ux(\sin u - \cos u)\frac{du}{dx}=(u^2+1)\cos u $

$\Rightarrow \int \frac{u(\sin u - \cos u)}{(u^2+1)\cos u}du = \int\frac{1}{x} dx$

Can you continue from there?

Edit: lol it appears I can't solve this integral after trying, perhaps someone could comment where I've gone wrong?

Comment: As far as I see, there is no mistake. Even Wolfram|Alpha cannot find the solution to this [differential equation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x*cos(y%2Fx)(x%2By*y%27)%3Dy*sin(y%2Fx)*(x*y%27-y)), nor the [left hand side integral](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x(sin(x)-cos(x))%2F((x%5E2%2B1)*cos(x))) too. +1 from me.

Comment: Yes. There isn't any calculation error.I tried solving but the left hand side integral doesn't have any fundamental form.